# About ASP.NET Gridview

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

Hi I need help implementing a logic using Gridview control in c#.

I have a gridview and it has many rows. Each row has a Button to click for the user. On each button click i am updating the selected record in the database. Now once row is updated, I need to hide that button to prevent reaction just for that particular row.
1. If i use this

```
<asp:CommandField ShowEditButton="True" EditText="select" />
```

, I can't make this hide.
2. If I use this

```
<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Your Action">
  <ItemTemplate>
    <asp:Button
        ID="btnAccept"
        runat="server"
        Text="Accept" 
        OnClientClick="return confirm('Are you sure you want to Accept this offer?');" 
        onclick="btnAccept_Click" />
  </ItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>
```

, I can't get the selected row index.

I hope i have cleared what i wanna ask. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use Button control's [CommandArgument](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.button.commandargument.aspx) property specify the row user clicked :

```
<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Your Action">
  <ItemTemplate>
    <asp:Button
        ID="btnAccept"
        runat="server"
        Text="Accept" 
        OnClientClick="return confirm('Are you sure you want to Accept this offer?');" 
        CommandName="Accept"
        CommandArgument='<%# Eval("RowId") %>'
        onclick="btnAccept_Click" />
  </ItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>
```

At code behind :

```
void btnAccept_Click(Object sender, CommandEventArgs e) 
{
    if (e.CommandName == "Accept")
    {
       string rowId = e.CommandArgument;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Continuing on Canavars solution for 1):

```
void btnAccept_Click(Object sender, CommandEventArgs e) 
{
    if (e.CommandName == "Accept")
    {
       string rowId = e.CommandArgument;
       ((Button)sender).Visible = false;
    }
}
```